# Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: UNC path is missing hostname: /\/

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to figure out a way to solve my problem. I am using `java.nio`. When i execute `Paths.get("/","/").toString()` in Linux environment, it is working fine as it is Linux based path. But when i execute it in Windows environment, it gives me the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: UNC path is missing hostname: /\/
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:113)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
```

I understand this is not a valid path system in Windows. Is there any way so that i can work for both Windows and Linux?

Note:
There are lot of hard coded Forward Slash in our application.

Comment: Hey, if any of the answers worked for you, perhaps you can show some appreciation  by accepting one of those. If they didn't work for you, feel free to comment on why not.

Answer (score 1):

`Paths.get("/","/")` is trivially useless, so I've no idea what your real use case is. However, you should *never* need to use hard-coded file separator in your code.

Assuming you want to get the root directory of a file system, you could do 2 things:

1. `Paths.get(".").getRoot()` would return `/` if `$PWD=/home/blah`
2. `FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()`

If you don't need the root directory, `Paths.get` would construct a `Path` using `File.separator`.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first parameter should be absolute, i.e. start with a path separator (`/` or `\`).

If the second value can be absolute, i.e. you want to ignore the preceding path, use:

```
Paths.get("/").resolve("/").toString()   // returns "\" on Windows
```